# using the Firefox Developer Toolbar from Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I use the Firefox Developer Toolbar to take screenshots (its pretty handy) but is there a way to trigger this functionality from Javascript? (specifically, from a bookmarklet?)